# socket.io emit not working when the receiver is offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

i want to receive the value from the user update it to the MongoDb and then forward it to receiver with specific targetId. Now when both the user are online then its working fine but when the receiver is offline then the app crash and error is cannot read property emit of undefined. Please help me in resolve this issue.

```
socket.on('data',Accmsg => {
    const findRsvpAndUpdate = (result,callback)=>{
        var value = summa.findOneAndUpdate(
            {$or:[{sourceId:Accmsg.sourceId,targetId:Accmsg.targetId},{sourceId: Accmsg.targetId,targetId: Accmsg.sourceId}]},
            {receive:Accmsg.receive,give:Accmsg.give,sourceId:Accmsg.sourceId,targetId:Accmsg.targetId},{upsert: true,new:true},
            function (error,results){
                if (error) {
                    callback(error);
                } else {
                    callback(null, results);
                }
            })
    }
        findRsvpAndUpdate(Accmsg, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log("The result is " +result);
                try {
                    let targetId = Accmsg.targetId;
                    clients[targetId].emit('clientAccount', Accmsg);// problem causing code line
                }catch (e){
                    console.log(e);
                }

            }
        });
});
```

Comment: check that `clients[targetId]` isn't undefined before calling `.emit()` on it.

Comment: because receiver not connected so `clients[targetId]` is not socket.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I used `try catch` to handle this error and now it's working fine.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.